# Does a charge moving through a dielectric at any speed create radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, dielectric

A moving charge has a corresponding electric field, which is time and position dependent. If the charge is moving through a dielectric, this electric field will induce a certain polarization in the material, which will this also depend on time.

But we know that dipoles oscillating in time emit radiation. So does a charge moving through a dielectric cause the dielectric to emit radiation? If so, how much?

This is all very reminiscent of [Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation), but I don't see why this wouldn't hold for all speeds, not just speeds that are higher than the phase velocity of the charge.

The only reason I can come up with that there would be no radiation, is that the radiation from a volume element polarizing in front of the charge would destructively interfere with radiation from a volume element depolarizing in the wake of the charge. But I sadly don't know how to quantitatively prove this. And if this is true, does it not hold for Cherenkov radiation?